# Excel Average based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I am trying to create a formula to get the average value of one column that meets the criteria from two other columns. I have figured out a simpler one using an array, but i am attempting something more complex.

"=AVERAGE(IF((B:B="SRVC")+(B:B="TIRSVC"),E:E))" is the one I have created successfully. I am trying to add to this by also including row D and a new formula if the value is 5 or less, 6-10, 11-15 and so on to greater than 50. Any thoughts or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IF(((B:B="SRVC")+(B:B="TIRSVC"))*(D:D<=5),E:E))`

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IF(((B:B="SRVC")+(B:B="TIRSVC"))*(D:D<=10)*(D:D>=6),E:E))`

Comment: But beware the more full column references one adds the more calcs this one formula will do.  It is better practice to limit the range reference to the dataset .